# jQuery removeClass only working with actual class name, not var

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I created a page to play around with the 960 Grid System, learn about div placement.  There are up to four divs on the page.  When a new grid size, pull or push value is selected from a dropdown, I need to remove the current class, i.e. `grid_8`, `pull_5` or `push_4`, and add the newly selected class.

```
function alter_grid1(new_class_name){

   var old = document.getElementById('grid1');
   var classes = old.className.split(' ');
   var old_class_name = 'cessna';
   $.each(classes, function(){

        if(old_class_name == 'cessna' || old_class_name == null){
          old_class_name = this.match('/grid_1|grid_2|grid_3|grid_4|grid_5|grid_6|grid_7|grid_8|grid_9|grid_10|grid_11|grid_12|grid_13|grid_14|grid_15|grid_16|grid_17/');
       }
   });
   $(old).removeClass('grid_1 grid_2 grid_3 grid_4 grid_5 grid_6 grid_7 grid_8 grid_9 grid_10 grid_11 grid_12 grid_13 grid_14 grid_15 grid_16').addClass(new_class_name);
   console.log('Old grid1 class name is ' + old_class_name + ' and New grid1 class name is ' + new_class_name);
}
```

I can use `addClass(new_class_name);` without any trouble.

I can use use `removeClass('grid_8');` without any trouble (grid_8 being the actual class name)

When I use `removeClass(old_class_name);` it just doesn't work.  No error message, nothing in firebug, just doesn't work.

Since I don't know what the previous value will be, I have to remove any possible class that could be there

```
 $(old).removeClass('grid_1 grid_2 grid_3 grid_4 grid_5 grid_6 grid_7 grid_8 grid_9 grid_10 grid_11 grid_12 grid_13 grid_14 grid_15 grid_16').addClass(new_class_name);
```

That's the only way I can get it to work.  Sure it works, but seems like I'm either missing something or doing something wrong.  You can see what I'm [trying to do here](http://style.chouinard.me/grid/multi_grid) if it would help.  I just don't see how I can add a class using a var, but not remove one the same way.

Comment: `match` returns an array, not a string.

Comment: Why do you set the variable `old_class_name='cessna'` and then check whether it's `'cessna'` or `null`?

Comment: @Niklas  I'm quite new to Javascript/jQuery, and I'm always changing something trying to get this to work.  That's just a remnant of my trial and error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems your regex is wrong. Use either a string without the slashes or just the slashes.

```
old_class_name = this.match(/grid_1|grid_2|grid_3|grid_4|grid_5|grid_6|grid_7|grid_8|grid_9|grid_10|grid_11|grid_12|grid_13|grid_14|grid_15|grid_16|grid_17/);
```

or maybe even

```
old_class_name = this.match(/grid_[0-9]+/);
```

Comment: using `this.match(/grid_[0-9]+/);` matches the class name, but `removeClass(old_class_name);` still won't work.  Using firebug I can see it's the correct value, and it's adding the new class just fine using a var.  And removing the quotes from the regex like you suggested results in matching `grid_1` every time.

Comment: the result is an array of strings. use `removeClass(old_class_name.join(' '))`.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick!  But I'm confused.  When I log `old_class_name` to firebug console it shows the class name that needs to be removed.  When I used the actual class name like that instead of the var, it worked just fine.  Is what's being sent to the console different than what's being sent to the removeClass function?

Comment: you're right it shouldn't be different. sure it's not `["grid_1"]` and not `"grid_1"`?

Comment: I'm using `console.log('Old grid1 class name is ' + old_class_name + ' and New grid1 class name is ' + new_class_name);`  and in the console it shows up as `grid_1` just as I had used successfully with removeClass.  Great that it works, I'd just like to understand why it took the join to get it there.

Comment: the console probably converts the array to a string, i know chrome does it. try logging the variable by itself or use the debugger to watch it.